# CouchDB: conditionally changing a value in Map/Reduce output to a negative

Tags: javascript, mapreduce, couchdb

I have numeric data in categories in CouchDB 1.6.1.

The documents would look something like this:

```
{
category1: "xxx",
category2: "yyy",
category3: "zzz",
value1: 20
}
{
category1: "xxx",
category2: "bbb",
category3: "ccc",
value1: 20
}
{
category1: "xxx",
category2: "lll",
category3: "mmm",
value1: 10
}
```

Map/Reduce function:

```
function(doc)
emit([doc.category1, doc.category2, doc.category3], value1)
reduce: _sum
```

group level 1 would give the total of 50.(20+20+10)

What I wish to achieve is to convert value1 to a negative number if say category3 === 'mmm'.

group level 1 would then give the answer 30 (20+20+(-10))

I have tried the following map function:

```
function(doc)
if(doc.category3 === 'mmm'){
doc.value1 = doc.value1 * -1; //(or, doc.value1 = -doc.value1)
emit([doc.category1, doc.category2, doc.category3], value1)
reduce: _sum
```

Result: no output.

I also tried:

```
function(doc)
var x = doc.value1;
if(doc.category3 === 'mmm'){
-Math.abs(x);
emit([doc.category1, doc.category2, doc.category3], x)
reduce: _sum
```

Result: error: invalid value.

and:

```
function(doc)
var x = doc.value1;
if(doc.category3 === 'mmm'){
-Math.abs(x);
emit([doc.category1, doc.category2, doc.category3], value1)
reduce: _sum
```

Result: completely incorrect answer.

Sorry, I know this is a simple question but I can't find an answer at this stage.

Is it possible to point me in the right direction please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first thing to note is that doc and its properties are immutable from your map and reduce functions. You can take things out of doc and assign them to temporary variables and manipulate them, but you can't change doc, which is what you're trying to do in your first example.

I can't quite tell what the problem with tries 2 and 3 are, since it looks like you didn't include all the JS, but it looks like you're not assigning the changed value to your temporary variable. Here's the function worked up for the document in question:

```js
var d1 = {
category1: "xxx",
category2: "lll",
category3: "mmm",
value1: 10
}

var emit = function(){
  var key = arguments[0];
  var value = arguments[1];
  console.log({"key": key, "value": value});
  } 



var _map = function(doc){
  var x = doc.value1;
  if (doc.category3 !== "mmm"){
    emit([doc.category1, doc.category2, doc.category3], x);
  }else{
    x = (-1 * Math.abs(x));
    emit([doc.category1, doc.category2, doc.category3], x);
  }
}

_map(d1)
```

The map function should do what you want.

Comment: Worked just fine. The " x = (-1 * Math.abs(x)); " was what I didn't get right. Again, many thanks.